# Filtering not working when images are LazyLoaded-ionic

Tags: angularjs, lazy-loading, ionic-framework

In my app I am loading some images with LAzyloading. I have used the following plugin for that:
https://github.com/paveisistemas/ionic-image-lazy-load.

It works well. Then I included filtering so that I can filter images based on image name.
But it is not working. No matter what name I give in the text box to filter, only the first image in the list is being shown.

This is my code for filtering in html:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="op in outputphotos  | myFilter:text track by $index" id="s"
    class="a"   type="item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/photo/{{op.id}}">

<image-lazy-src="{{op.url}}" height="150px" width="150px" alt="">

</ion-item>
```

But filtering worked well before adding the LAzyLoad function.
How can I get both lazyload and filtering working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used infinte-scroll plugin instead of ionic-image-lazy-load and now both filtering and lazyloading works well.

This is my code after adding infinite-scroll:

```
 <ion-item ng-repeat="op in outputphotos  | myFilter:text track by $index" id="s" class="a"   type="item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/photo/{{op.id}}">

    <img ng-src="{{op.url}}" height="150px" width="150px" alt="">

  </ion-item>
  <ion-infinite-scroll ng-if="!noMoreItemsAvailable" on-infinite="loadMore()" distance="5%"></ion-infinite-scroll>
```